# Firefox addon - is it possible to capture text/html from the webpage?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have never wrote a firefox addon so I am wondering if this can be done. Is it possible to continually scan a webpage for certain text, and then if that text appears, capture it and save it to a file?

For example

1. Say a user is on amazon and adds a few items to their shopping cart.
2. They click checkout and fill in their details and click submit order.
3. When the order is processed the user is shown the text 'Order complete' and given a receipt of their purchase.

In this example I would like to keep scanning the webpage until 'Order complete' appears. Then I want to capture the html of the receipt and save it to a file.

Is this possible with a firefox addon?

Answer (score 2):

From my experience as a Firefox user, this is definitely possible. As a matter of fact there are add-ons that do far more than that.

For example, [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) can actually act as a filter and *change* the content of a viewed webpage as specified by a user script. [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/) and [AlertBox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/distill-web-monitor-ff/) are able to selectively watch specific HTML elements for interesting information and act upon it.

It is also quite possible that there is an existing add-on that either does what you need already, or can be used as a basis for a custom add-on of your own - what you are asking for is not all that unusual...

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create your add-on with the [Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder). You can then use the [`page-mod` package](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/packages/addon-kit/docs/page-mod.html) to attach a content script to Amazon pages. The content script should check whether it got loaded into an order confirmation page - and send the HTML code of that page (probably `document.body.innerHTML`) back to the extension.

The extension then needs to write the data to a file. You need to use [internal API](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/packages/api-utils/docs/file.html) for that, something like this:

```
var file = require("file");
var writer = file.open("c:\\foo\\bar.html", "w");
writer.writeAsync(data);
```

If you want the user to choose the file name, you can do this using [chrome authority](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/dev-guide/module-development/chrome.html) and [`nsIFilePicker` component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIFilePicker).